# How do I Quit a Multi-Threaded GUI with wxpython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, user-interface, wxpython

Very simple question. How do I make this program quit 5 seconds after the 'run()' function completes?

```
# Import Libraries
import requests, os, sys, zipfile, shutil, subprocess, wx, urllib, time
from threading import *

# Define variables
url = "Insert any Dropbox .zip file link here"
r = requests.get(url, stream = True)
myEVT_PROGRESS = wx.NewEventType() # Custom Event Type
EVT_PROGRESS = wx.PyEventBinder(myEVT_PROGRESS, 1) # bind specific events to event handlers

# Button definitions
ID_START = wx.NewId()

# Define notification event for thread completion
EVT_RESULT_ID = wx.NewId()

# Downloads new file
def Download():
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'File.zip')

# Extracts new file
def Extract():
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("File.zip", 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall("Folder")
    zip_ref.close()

# Deletes the .zip file but leave the folder
def Clean():
    os.remove("File.zip")

class ProgressEvent(wx.PyCommandEvent):
    """Event to signal that a status or progress changed"""
    def __init__(self, etype, eid, status=None, progress=None):
        """Creates the event object"""
        wx.PyCommandEvent.__init__(self, etype, eid)
        self._status = status       # field to update label
        self._progress = progress   # field to update progress bar

    def GetValue(self):
        """Returns the value from the event.
        @return: the tuple of status and progress
        """
        return (self._status, self._progress)

# Thread class that executes processing
class WorkerThread(Thread):
    """Worker Thread Class."""
    def __init__(self, notify_window):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._notify_window = notify_window
        self.setDaemon(1)
        # This starts the thread running on creation.
        self.start()

    # This is what runs on a separate thread when you click the download button
    def run(self):
        # This is the code executing in the new thread.
        self.sendEvent('Checking for old files...', 00)
        self.sendEvent('Checking for old files...', 100)
        time.sleep(.5)
        if os.path.exists("Folder"):
            self.sendEvent('Removing old files...', 200)
            subprocess.check_call(('attrib -R ' + 'Folder' + '\\* /S').split())
            shutil.rmtree('Folder')
            time.sleep(.3)
            self.sendEvent('Removed old files!', 300)
        else:
            time.sleep(.3)
            self.sendEvent('No old files found.', 300)
            time.sleep(.3)
            pass
        self.sendEvent('Downloading Package...', 400)
        Download()
        self.sendEvent('Downloading complete!', 600)
        time.sleep(.3)
        self.sendEvent('Extracting...', 650)
        Extract()
        self.sendEvent('Extraction complete!', 900)
        time.sleep(.3)
        self.sendEvent('Cleaning up...', 950)
        Clean()
        time.sleep(.3)
        self.sendEvent('Cleaning complete!', 1000)
        time.sleep(.3)
        self.sendEvent('Done!',
                       1000)
        time.sleep(5)

######### QUIT PROGRAM HERE #########

    def sendEvent(self, status=None, progress=None):
        # Send event to main frame, first param (str) is for label, second (int) for the progress bar
        evt = ProgressEvent(myEVT_PROGRESS, -1, status, progress)
        wx.PostEvent(self._notify_window, evt)

# GUI Frame class that spins off the worker thread
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """Class MainFrame."""    
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        """Create the MainFrame."""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'RFMP GUInstaller', 
                          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER
                          ^ wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        self.SetSize(400, 350)
        wx.Button(self, ID_START, 'Download', size=(300,50), pos=(42,250))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, id=ID_START)
        self.status = wx.StaticText(self, -1, '', pos=(7,200), style=wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.status.SetBackgroundColour((255,255,0)) # set text back color
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(self, range = 1000, size = (370, 30), pos=(7,217),
                              style =  wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)

        # And indicate we don't have a worker thread yet
        self.worker = None
        self.Bind(EVT_PROGRESS, self.OnResult) # Bind the custom event to a function

    def OnStart(self, event):
        # Trigger the worker thread unless it's already busy
        if not self.worker:
            self.status.SetLabel('')
            self.worker = WorkerThread(self)

    def OnResult(self, event):
        """Our handler for our custom progress event."""
        status, progress = event.GetValue()
        self.status.SetLabel(status)
        if progress:
            self.gauge.SetValue(progress)

class MainApp(wx.App):
    """Class Main App."""
    def OnInit(self):
        """Init Main App."""
        self.frame = MainFrame(None, -1)
        self.frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

# Main Loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Apparently, I need to add more details because there is to much code in my program, so here I am making a unnecessarily long sentence to make my post look more descriptive by the requirement of the stack overflow website that needs me to make my code much more descriptive or it won't let me post my very long code that I need help fixing because I just started coding GUI python yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Run` function, simply send a signal with a "Terminate" status and a progress value of something like -1.

```
self.sendEvent('Terminate...', -1)
```

Your `OnResult` function, then becomes something like this:

```
def OnResult(self, event):
    """Our handler for our custom progress event."""
    status, progress = event.GetValue()
    self.status.SetLabel(status)
    if progress >= 0:
        self.gauge.SetValue(progress)
    else:
        # The worker is done
        self.worker = None
        time.sleep(5)
        self.Close()
        self.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

In run() you can add:

```
import time
import sys
start = time.time()
PERIOD_OF_TIME = 5    # 5 seconds
...
your code
...
if time.time() > start + PERIOD_OF_TIME:
    sys.exit(0)    # 5 seconds up, quit program
```

Comment: In run(), you are doing `time.sleep()` for more than 5 seconds total, so the condition at the end will always resolve to true. But that sounds like a separate question from the one you posed.

Comment: Obviously this wasn't tested. sys.exit() will not correctly close my GUI or the currently running thread. I did however find the solution myself which I will be posting when I finish this project.